# Filtering an order collection by a custom customer attribute?

Tags: orders, customer, collection

I have created a custom customer attribute, let's call it *my_custom_attribute*.

I need to extend an order collection to include this custom customer attribute for each order.

I have solved this by joining the *customer_entity_varchar* (since the attribute is of the *varchar* type) table into the product collection, to get the customer's ID from that:

```
// First I figure out the internal attribute ID of the custom attribute
$attributeId = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getResource()->getAttribute('my_custom_attribute')->getId();

$collection->getSelect()
    ->joinLeft(
        array('customers' => Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('customer_entity_varchar')),
       'customers.entity_id = `main_table`.customer_id AND customers.attribute_id = ' . $attributeId,
        array('my_custom_attribute' => 'customers.value')
)
```

This works for me, but I feel like it's not a very elegant solution? Is there another more elegant way that I've overlooked?

Comment: Also was watching for solution. Found the following:
http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/19296/join-customer-custom-attribute-to-order-collection

Comment: Thanks, that looks interesting, but in my case I need to be able to dynamically update the custom attribute, and this change should also be reflected in the order collection.

Answer (score 1):

If it works it is ok. You have the `customer_id` in the `order` and you can join into the `varchar` table. I think it is fine.